# Django model name with underscore?

Tags: django, django-models

I have subtly different entities that are important enough with respect to the relationships, flexibility, and expression of my schema that they warrant separate models.

How should I name/ case these?

```
a) Layerinput, Layerhidden, Layeroutput

b) Layer_Input, Layer_Hidden, Layer_Output

c) LayerInput, LayerHidden, LayerOutput
```

Right now I am leaning option `a` so that Django doesn't do anything too automagically incorrect with them, but that won't look great in documentation and code. Will use them with either DRF or graphql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to naming Classes, you should choose c) as shown in image below (obtained from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names).[image]

If you're referring to the field_names (eg. name and age under the class CommonInfo in the figure above), then the convention for django is as followed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use camelCase (option c), this helps you differentiate words in a variable while minimising the characters (as in option b)

Use this as a guide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/

Comment: Do you know how it is interpreted by django?

Comment: Django interprets all the 3 as a variable name, it's just a naming convention for programmers to understand and adapt to the code. Also, a coding style is maintained. Look at the coding style(edited the main answer to include the link)

Answer (score 1):

According to [PEP8 conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names),

> Class names should normally use the **CapWords** convention.

These naming conventions are also followed in the Django framework. So you can choose the third option.

Comment: PEP8 is python coding style, django gives out additional info

Answer (score 0):

CamelCase (option c) is also useful because Django will know how to render your model names in the admin site. For example 'LayerInput' will appear correctly as 'Layer input' without you having to specify it anywhere.